# Does charge conjugation symmetry sit in the Lorentz group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, charge-conjugation, cpt-symmetry

We know the Lorentz group is $O(3,1)$ in 4 dimensional spacetime.

We know that there are 4 disconnected components in Lorentz group $O(3,1)$, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2204349/

$$\pi_0(\mathrm{O}(1,3))  \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2.$$

My question is that in QFT we have a discrete charge conjugation symmetry $C$, parity $P$ and time reversal $T$.

We know the $P$ and $T$ flips the 4 disconnected components of $O(3,1)$ into each other.

> How about the charge conjugation $C$, does it sit in the Lorentz group? Or does it only act on the matter field? How do we understand $C$ in the Lorentz group $O(3,1)$?

Comment: Charge lives in spacetime but is not part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QED, for example, charge conjugation commutes with the Lorentz group. It's an "internal" symmetry, not part of Lorentz (or Poincaré) symmetry.

However, a different kind of connection exists between charge conjugation and the Lorentz group, via the CPT theorem. The CPT theorem says that every relativistic QFT (satisfying certain axioms) has a symmetry that, among other things, reflects a timelike direction and an odd number of spatial directions. We call it the "CPT" theorem, but that's a little misleading, because it should be regarded as more fundamental (that is, more broadly applicable) than C, P, or T individually. In other words, we really ought to define charge conjugation in terms of CPT, not the other way around.

Here's the point: The general proof of the CPT theorem makes use of the *complex* Lorentz group (through the fact that correlation functions can be analytically continued to complex values of their spacetime arguments), and in this sense there is a kind of connection between C and Lorentz symmetry. This is reviewed in

- Greenberg (2003), "Why is CPT fundamental?", https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0309309

and in the classic text by Streater and Wightman, *PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That*.

Comment: thanks very much vote up

Comment: What does *complex* Lorentz group mean really? I thought the Lorentz group O(1,3) has a real Lie algebra thus a real Lie group? Do you mean Lorentz group as a complex Lie group or not? many thanks!

Comment: @anniemarieheart The usual Lorentz group is a real Lie group, like you said. The *complex* Lorentz group consists of linear transforms of $(t,x,y,z)$, with complex coefficients, that preserve $t^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Chapter 1 in *PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That* defines it in detail, and the rest of the book uses it heavily. The paper [hep-ph/0309309](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0309309) explains what it means and why it's relevant to CPT. [Ryan Thorngren's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549638) to another question also briefly explains why it's relevant.

Comment: Thanks so much -- accepted for now!